# How to pass a password with quotes and single quotes in terminal?

Tags: android, bash, shell, apk, keytool

I created a .keystore for my Android application, generating a random password. It contains quotes (") and singles quotes (') in the same password, like this one: xxxxxx"xxx!\x='x

I am trying to pass the password using keytool. How can I pass the password?

```
keytool -list -storepass "<my_password>" -keystore my.keystore
```

And shows:

> -bash: !\xx'x": event not found

Thanks!

**EDIT**
I tried using:

```
keytool -list -storepass xxxxxx\"xxx\!x=\'x -keystore my.keystore
```

> keytool error: java.io.IOException: Keystore was tampered with, or
>   password was incorrect

Comment: Why not generate a password without (`"`) quotes? Did you just create this?

Comment: @JaredBurrows I created it. Definitely I am not going to use ( " , ' , \ ) anymore.

Comment: Ok good. So you can just create a new one. Keep it secret, keep it safe.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I guess you have to escape the special characters, like this:

`xxxxxx\"xxx\\!xx\'x`

Comment: It is not working. I think the problem is not only the quotes, it is also the '!\x' part.

Comment: I correct xxxxxx\"xxx\!xx\'x ... we have to scape !, ' and "

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know what history expansion is, you don't use it, or you don't know whether you use it, append `set +H` to your `.bashrc` to disable it. This will stop interactive bash sessions from messing with your otherwise well placed exclamation marks.

You can also just run `set +H` from your prompt to disable it for that session:

```
$ echo "!foo"
bash: !foo: event not found

$ set +H

$ echo "!foo"
!foo
```

Alternatively, you can work around it by putting exclamation marks in single quotes:

```
$ echo "fo'o!ba\\r"
bash: !ba\\r: event not found

$ echo "fo'o"'!'"ba\\r"
fo'o!ba\r
```

Here the double quoted string is used as is, but the `!` is replaced by `"'!'"` which closes the double quotes, starts a single quoted segment, adds the `!`, then closes the single quotes and opens a double quoted string again.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I can use echo "xxxxxx"xxx"'!'"\x='x" and it shows the password. But then I pass the same in _-storepass_ for keytool and it continues showing the same error message. Maybe keytool uses some weird algorithm?

Comment: What you posted appears to be missing a quote so it can't be used, and your edit shows a distinctly different error message than the "event not found" you had before, and indicates that you're using the wrong password. You have to keep in mind that unescaped quotes are shell syntax and are not passed to keytool, so if you input `foo"bar"` as a password while running keytool (as opposed to when starting keytool), specifying `-storepass foo"bar"` will not work (instead, you'd have to use something like `-storepass 'foo"bar"'`)

Answer (score 0):

I would stick the password into a variable

```
pass='xxxxxx"xxx!\x='\''x'
```

The `'\''` bit is one way to embed a single quote into a single quoted string in bash.

Then you can just use the variable in double quotes

```
cmd -p "$pass"
```