# use single quote in command line for the password

Tags: linux, bash

I have a `.php` file which name is console.php and I want to set password from command like with this script all things is ok and I use it like this

```
php console.php user password
// f.e.
php console.php admin 1234
```

But when I want to use the a strong password which contain a single quote f.e. **123'456** it does not work and go to the next line like this

```
azibom@azibom:~$ php console.php admin 123'456
>
```

Is there any solution for it?

Comment: [How to pass a password with quotes and single quotes in terminal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29615061/how-to-pass-a-password-with-quotes-and-single-quotes-in-terminal)

Answer (score 1):

You can escape characters which have special meaning to the shell: `123\'456`.

Comment: yes I know, I can also put them in the double qoute like this "123'456" but I want to know that, is there any other solution for it

Comment: @azibom If you mean "is there any solution that doesn't require quoting or escaping", the answer is no. Any command you type in a shell command line must be written in the shell language, and in the shell language an unescaped and unquoted single-quote means "this is the beginning of a quoted string, that ends with another single quote". You cannot change this meaning, it is built into the shell language.

Comment: @azibom: Yes, it is: Store the password (using your favorite text editor) into a file, say `secret_password.txt`, and do a `php console.php admin $(<secret_password.txt)`. This makes it also easier if you want to change the password later, and it also helps evil hackers to find your password, without looking through your scripts.

Comment: @user1934428 Using `$(<secret_password.txt)` without double-quotes around it will cause trouble if the password contains whitespace, and maybe also if it contains anything that can be mistaken for a shell filename wildcard. If someone's been messing with `IFS`, things can get even weirder. So I wouldn't really recommend this method.

Comment: @GordonDavisson : Of course, I forgot the quotes: `php console.php admin "$(<secret_password.txt)"`.